# Reopening my question about destroying file contents

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions, reopen-request

I rewrote my question
[How to destroy file contents without deleting files](https://superuser.com/questions/608000/how-to-destroy-file-contents-without-deleting-files). I believe now it's not asking for the shopping advice.
Is there anything I can do to the question so that it is no longer off-topic and gets reopened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reopened the question. I thought it has merit.